# Steam Web API : How Can I Get list of all items for game ids(570, 440, 730, 753) with tags & description

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

Is this possible to get all items with their **TAGS** like

```
(Rarity,Quality,Hero,Slot,Type,Description)
```

for **DOTA2**(570), **TF2**(440), **CS:GO**(730), **Steam**(753)

I haven't found any api to get response with all items available for particular game.If anyone know how to get this please reply to my question.

Comment: duplicate question, somehow, it got answered later : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977803/steam-web-api-getting-csgo-inventory/26011027#26011027 cheers

Answer (score 7):

There's no official API (e.g. the Web API) to get all information for all games. Web API only supports Dota 2 (`IEconItem_570`) and TF2 (`IEconItems_440`). There’s also an interface for CS:GO (`IEconItem_730`), but it's rudimentary and doesn't include weapon skins.

Because of that lack of official APIs Steam Condenser doesn't include a way to do this.

There's a way to mimic Steam's own web interface and mobile apps which use a JSON interface, e.g. http://steamcommunity.com/id/koraktor/inventory/json/730/2/ (where 730 is the app ID and 2 is the item type). Steam use other types than `2`: `3`, `6` and `7`. The data structure is almost self-explanatory.
The language can be changed by setting the GET parameter `l` to the name of the language, e.g. `english`, `german` or `french` .