# Steam Web Api: CS:GO Getting Skin name of items

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

So I"m using steam api get the player's inventory items and then the schema to get the item names.
Backpack: http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/
Schema: http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v0002/

But it only gives me the original item name for example

M4A4 instead of M4A4 | Faded Zebra (Battle-Scarred)

How can I get the added skin name to the weapon name?

I also tried lookating the attributes defindexes but defindex don't seem to link to skin names in the csgo_english.txt.

Comment: As per the question linked it looks like you can't get the skin names (unless it's changed since then!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840334/steam-web-api-how-can-i-get-list-of-all-items-for-game-ids570-440-730-753

Answer (score 3):

The skins information is saved as an attribute of the item itself.  Look for the item's attributes with the defindex of 6, it's value is equal to the identifier in the schema paint_kits section.  Then you'll have to translate the schema paint name to your native language to get something readable instead of aq_oiled or some other such nonsense.  Lastly to get the (Battle-scarred) bit just look at the attribute with defindex of 8's float_value to determine what the wear on the skin is.

Comment: Please add some example and explanation.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old question, but I've been trying to figure this out for at least two hours now. Where are the paint_kits section? I cannot find it anywhere.